# Issues with Graph-It (Geometry Homework)

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

You are working on your geometry homework (graphic quadratics) and become bored of drawing the axes over and over again. Instead, you find an online tool called Graph-It that you use to graph the quadratics easily. For the first couple graphs, it worked fine... but then, you started to get an error message rather than a graph:

`GRAPH CANNOT BE DISPLAYED! Error code: MEL#NBHPBNTMGL#LNCTKHOLEW#RZNY`

You try many times, but still get the same message.

Frustrated, you go onto an online forum where haters of the Graph-It application can vent their frustration (it's creatively named Die, Graph-It):

```
geo_luver_122: this is dumb i keep getting this error code --> G##MEDCZXKCBUMXODUQJKCBFLCNFBNEYCPQHGQTNLW

    pandabear55: @geo_luver_122 Me 2! IDK why! Sometimes i get this error also --> GU#LNCRBNWTGJZAPHOLJHBEZONOIPKEQUOJOIGUPAJOZEYHZ

        geniusman5000: @geo_luver_122 @pandabear55 lol u guys r noobz theres a good reason u cant access those graphs

        geniusman5000: @geo_luver_122 @pandabear55 btw imma tell ur teachers lol
```

**What's the deal with Graph-It? When can you not access the graphs? What will `geniusman5000` tell `pandabear55`'s and `geo_luver_122`'s teachers?**

#### Hints

Hint 1:

> The error messages are the most relevant piece of the puzzle!

Hint 2:

> Look at them tags!

Comment: imagine if this actually happened to you

Comment: @matt -- That would be unfortunate!

Comment: i'd imagine so :p

Comment: The only reason I got this puzzle was by looking through a list of ciphers, because I knew you had made puzzles that were very similar to this before. "Guess the cipher" puzzles generally aren't very interesting, and if you don't know that the cipher already exists there's nothing really pointing towards them. (The point of ciphers is *not* to be cracked!)

Comment: Is wordplay really appropriate here? I suppose ciphers *would* be too obvious, but wordplay...

Comment: @Quintec -- die graph it = digrafid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be

> messages encoded with the ["Digrafid cipher"](https://www.dcode.fr/digrafid-cipher), which is a thing I had never heard of before.
>
>  They decode to:
>  `DONOTCHEATONYOURMATHHOMEWORK##`
>  `YOUARELITERALLYINTHEMIDDLEOFANEXAMRIGHTNOW`
>  `YOURPARENTSHAVEGROUNDEDYOUNOELECTRONICSALLOWED##`

What's the deal with Graph-It?
When can you not access the graphs?
What will geniusman5000 tell pandabear55's and geo_luver_122's teachers?

> It looks like you can't graph things from specific homework assignments or exams, and geniusman5000 will tell the teachers of the other two that they were cheating.

Comment: To be fair, the name of the Chat Room does point you _ever so slightly_ towards the name of the cipher, although kudos to you — I’d never have gotten that far.

Comment: @el-guest Yeah, but the only way I would've known that it was that in particular is if I already knew how the puzzle worked. Without knowing that I should be digging through lists of ciphers from OP's precious puzzles, I would have no way to figure out which specific phrase I should corrupt in what specific way, to find the search terms I actually need.

Comment: agreed — I’m saying all this in hindsight, but as I mentioned I couldn’t have worked my way forward to arrive at this answer myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "precious puzzles?"

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Meant "previous" - typo, sorry!

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Thanks for the feedback, even if I disagree. Before I accept, make sure you answer all questions; though you've done all the work, you haven't answered any of the questions asked.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to accept; I completely forgot about this!